# Getting Best Signal With RG6

Tags: television, coaxial-cable, internet

I have recently "cut-the-cord" and have dropped my TV service through my provider, so the only need for a RG6 cable is my cable internet service.  My set-up is that the "orange" cable that leads from the pole to my house connects to a 6-way splitter like this:
[image: splitter]

Cables run all through the home, but the only one that matters is the ONE cable that connects to the modem.  My question is, will I see a difference if I continue to use the 6-way splitter, or if I change to what I'll call a "coupler" like the image below:
[image: Coupler]

Will I see any increase in modem signal/internet performance etc etc if I switch to the "coupler"?

Comment: Those couplers are often called barrel connectors.

Comment: Is this simply a question about the internet?  or TV. No need to have your TV on this wire. Get a proper over the air TV Antenna and if your TV needs internet it should be getting it from your router.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want a splitter where the -db is smaller. The bigger the -#, or smaller, the more signal that is lost. I personally choose a -3.5 splitters and run 1 specifically to the modem and then the other to another splitter for the tvs. It starts at 0 from the orange cable.

There is good article over at http://eqrunner.com/CrewNotes/CNCoaxsplitter.php that goes into all the details.

Comment: Is there a device or a tool that would allow me to check the -#db on the line?  - this is what I'm currently showing, are these numbers good?  https://pastebin.com/uARpMaJG

Comment: Not sure if I should be looking at power or snr

Comment: @user2676140 Ideally both power would increase by the difference in the db loss between the two connectors while SNR would remain unchanged.  In the real world both the 1:1 coupler and the 6:1 splitter both probably introduce a non-zero amount of noise into the signal which would impact the SNR.  All things equal I'd assume the coupler being a simpler design would add less noise.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you are getting an acceptable signal level at the router, replacing the six-way splitter with a coupler won't accomplish much. You can tell via a speed test, which is readily available on the web. However, reliability will be improved by replacement.

If you install the coupler, save the splitter for possible future applications

Comment: Replacing the splitter might help, and it certainly couldn't hurt.  As the answer points out, it depends on whether the modem is already getting an acceptable signal or not.  Even if it doesn't help now, it might help in the future when faster connection speeds are available.  If it were me, I'd replace it.

Answer (score 1):

By eliminating the splitter your signal will be stronger at the modem. The question will be do you need a stronger signal?

Comment: My speeds are as they should be - I just have regular drops which is why I'm interested to see if this would make a diff.

Comment: It may resolve some packet loss if you are on the edge defiantly worth bypassing if you don't need the other taps.